# MLEs for shifted exponential distribution: what am I doing wrong and how do I calculate them?

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have the i.i.d. exponential random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$ with the density functions

$$f(x; \sigma, \tau)=
\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{\sigma} e^{-(x - \tau)/\sigma} &\text{if}\, x\geq \tau\\
      0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimators for $\sigma$ and $\tau$. I calculate the likelihood as

$$L(\sigma \mid \mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i = 1}^n f(x_i; \sigma, \tau)\mathbf{1}_{x \ge \tau} = \prod_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sigma} \exp{ \left\{ -\left( \dfrac{x_i - \tau}{\sigma} \right) \right\} }\mathbf{1}_{x \ge \tau} = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^n} \exp{ \left\{ -\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i - \tau}{\sigma} \right) \right\} }\mathbf{1}_{x \ge \tau}$$

So now to find the MLEs, we just calculate $\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\sigma}} = 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\tau}} = 0$, right?

$\dfrac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\sigma}} = \dfrac{-\exp{ \left\{ -\left( \dfrac{ \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + \tau}{\sigma} \right) \right\} } (-y - d) - n\exp{ \left\{ -\left( \dfrac{ \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + \tau}{\sigma} \right) \right\} } (\sigma)}{x^{2 + n}} = 0$

I strongly suspect that I'm doing this incorrectly. Can someone please show me what I'm doing incorrectly and how we actually calculate these two MLE?

Comment: You're missing one crucial step: in the step with the product, the indicator should be
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{x_i \geq \tau} = \mathbf{1}_{\min(x_i) \geq \tau}\text{.}$$
This is equivalent to saying: $x_1, \dots, x_n \geq \tau$ if and only if $\min(x_i) \geq \tau$. 

The procedure of setting your derivatives equal to $0$ only makes sense if your likelihood function is differentiable over all real numbers, which is NOT the case here.

Comment: @Clarinetist Oh, yes, that makes sense. But I still don't understand what we're supposed to do to calculate the two MLEs.

Comment: MLE of shift is min observed value, but that is biased. So you can find the dist'n of the min and use that to find an unbiased estimator.

Comment: @BruceET As I said in my comment to Pedro, the next exercise part after this one asks to find whether the estimators that I found are unbiased, so this seems to imply that we should be able to calculate the two MLEs. These are simple practice exercises, so I'm not sure that they're meant to be too difficult.

Comment: [Finding Max Likelihood Estimators for the following Shifted Exponential PDF?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631223/finding-max-likelihood-estimators-for-the-following-shifted-exponential-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your likelihood function is

${L}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{n}} \exp\left\{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{\sigma}\right\}1_{\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau}$

where we used that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}1_{x_{i}\geq\tau}=1_{\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau}$.

First, let's find the MLE of $\tau$. Notice that $L$ is increasing in $\tau$ for $\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau$. Therefore, the value of $\tau$ that maximizes the likelihood function is $\tau^{MLE}=\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}$, because if $\tau>\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}$ the $L=0$.

Now let's turn to the MLE estimator of $\sigma$. A useful tool is to maximize the log-likelihood instead of the likelihood. Since it is a monotonic transformation then the value of $\sigma$ that maximizes $L$ is the same that the one that maximizes $\log L$. The log likelihood for $\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau$ (because of our previous discussion) is

$
\log L = -n\log \sigma - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{\sigma}$

Taking the derivative:
$
\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial\sigma}=0\implies \sigma^{MLE}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{n}$

Since $\sigma^{MLE}$ depends on $\tau$ which is unkown it is frequent to replace $\tau$ with $\tau^{MLE}$. This is called the plug-in principle. Therefore, the MLE estimates for $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are:
$
\tau^{MLE}=\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\qquad \sigma^{MLE}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\right)}{n}$

Now to your final question of whether these estimates are unbiased or not. You can easily check that $\tau^{MLE}$ is **not** unbiased. Intuitively: if you took many samples the minimum will be on avarege above $\tau$. For $\sigma$, if $\tau^{MLE}$ was unbiased then it would be a direct result that $\sigma^{MLE}$ is unbiased, since it is just the sample mean. However, because $\tau^{MLE}$ is biased then $\sigma^{MLE}$ will also be biased.

Comment: Huh? But this practice exercise says to calculate the maximum likelihood estimators for $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Surely it wouldn't ask me this if it wasn't possible?

Comment: Calculate the MLE does is not equivalent to taking the derivative. In fact, when the support of the distribution depends on an unknown parameter you cannot take the derivative

Comment: Hmm, ok, I see. The textbook that I am reading didn't seem to explain this. But I still don't understand how I'm supposed to calculate these two MLEs.

Comment: Let me update my original answer to explain you step by step.

Comment: Thank you. The next exercise part after this one asks to find whether the estimators that I found are unbiased, so this seems to imply that we should be able to calculate the two MLEs, right?

Comment: Also, as you said, I think I should have differentiated the *log*-likelihood, rather than the straight likelihood.

Comment: There you go. Both of your statements are correct. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that! Aren't you missing the negative inside the exponential term ${L}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{n}}exp\left\{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{\sigma}\right\}1_{\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau}$?

Comment: Yes, let me correct htat

Comment: Now that we've added the negative and have ${L}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{n}}exp\left\{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{\sigma}\right\}1_{\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau}$, does that still mean that $L$ is increasing in $\tau$ for $\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau$? Can you please explain what this means?

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo.

Comment: Great, that all makes sense to me! Thanks! To verify whether it is biased,  I just calculate the expected value of $\frac{1}{\sigma^{n}} \exp\left\{\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\tau\right)}{\sigma}\right\}1_{\min\left\{x_{i}\right\}\geq \tau}$ and compare it to the expected value of $\tau^{\text{MLE}}$ and $\sigma^{\text{MLE}}$?

Comment: No, no calculate the expected value of $\tau^{MLE}$ and $\sigma^{MLE}$ and compare it to $\tau$ and $\sigma$. For the first case, you have to compute the distribution of the minimum of a sample. For the second, you can use the following decomposition: $\mathbb{E}\sigma^{MLE}=\mathbb{E}\bar{X} - \mathbb{E}\tau^{MLE}$ and that $\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\bar{X}=\sigma+\tau$.

Comment: Ok, I will do this and see what I get. Thanks for taking the time to help!