# Maximum likelihood estimator with indicator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be the sample from distribution with density
$$
p_{\alpha,\beta}(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha}e^{(\beta−x)/\alpha}I_{[\beta,+\infty)}(x).
$$
where $θ = (\alpha,\beta)$ is a two-dimensional parameter. I need to find the maximum likelihood estimate for $θ$.
The problem is that after finding $f_{\theta}(x_1,..,x_n) = \frac{1}{\alpha^n}e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\beta−x_i)/\alpha}I\left\{\min(X_1, .., X_n) \geq \beta\right\}$ and taking logarithm from this function, I'm having a hard time finding derivatives with respect to the parameters, since there is an indicator here.
I think since $f_{\theta}$ is decreasing when $\min(X_1, .., X_n)$ becomes bigger than $\beta$ and for $\min(X_1, .., X_n) < \beta$, $f_{\theta} = 0$, so maximum likelihood estimation for $\beta$ equal $\min(X_1, .., X_n)$, then it's easy to find, that maximum likelihood estimation for $\alpha$ equal $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \min(X_1, .., X_n)$. Is it right?
And there is a question how to check, that estimation for $\alpha$ is asymptotically normal? I would be grateful for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivation of the maximum likelihood estimator is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631223/finding-the-maximum-likelihood-estimators-for-this-shifted-exponential-pdf) in detail.

Let $X_{(1)}:=\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ be the first order statistic.

Note that the likelihood is **increasing** in $\beta$ as long as $X_{(1)}\ge \beta$, which gives you the MLE $$\hat\beta=X_{(1)}$$

Then differentiating the likelihood with respect to $\alpha$ does give you the MLE

$$\hat\alpha=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-X_{(1)}=\overline X_n-X_{(1)}$$

As for a **hint** on checking asymptotic normality of $\hat\alpha$, first observe that $X_i$'s are shifted exponentials:

$$X_i-\beta \sim \text{Exp}(\text{mean}=\alpha)$$

So the population mean is

$$E(X_i)=\alpha+\beta$$

Now,

\begin{align}
\sqrt n(\hat\alpha-\alpha)&=\sqrt n(\overline X_n-X_{(1)}-\alpha-\beta+\beta)
\\&=\sqrt n(\overline X_n-(\alpha+\beta))-\sqrt n(X_{(1)}-\beta)
\end{align}

What can you say about the convergence of the second term in particular?

Indeed, a straightforward calculation of the distribution function shows that $\sqrt n(X_{(1)}-\beta)$ converges in distribution to $0$. Hence it also converges in probability to $0$:

$$\sqrt n(X_{(1)}-\beta) \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow 0$$

Applying Slutsky's theorem then gives you the answer.

The theorem you are alluding to regarding asymptotic normality of sample quantiles is true for *central order statistics*. One version of this is

> Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d with cdf $F$. Let $\sqrt n\left(\frac{k_n}{n}-p\right)\to 0$ for some $0<p<1$ as $n\to \infty$. If $\xi_p$ is the $p$th population quantile and if $F'(\xi_p)$ exists with $F'(\xi_p)>0$, then
> $$\sqrt n(X_{(k_n)}-\xi_p) \stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac{p(1-p)}{(F'(\xi_p))^2}\right)$$

As you can see, the above does not apply to sample extremes like $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$. The extremes have separate asymptotics. In this problem, you can check that $n(X_{(1)}-\beta)\sim Z$ where $Z$ is Exponential with mean $\alpha$. So the following gives a non-degenerate limiting distribution of $X_{(1)}$:

$$n(X_{(1)}-\beta)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow Z$$

Notably, the limit is non-normal and the norming constant is $n$ instead of $\sqrt n$.

Comment: I think $X_i - \beta$ has distribution $Exp(\frac{1}{\alpha})$

Comment: About second term, i think, we can say that it converges to normal distribution, since there is a theorem, which says: $\sqrt{n}(X_{(k)} - z_{p}) \xrightarrow{d_{\theta}} N(0, ...)$, where $z_{p}$ is a p-quantile and $k = np + O(1)$. In our example $k = 1$ and $\beta$ is a $0$-quantile

Comment: as i understood you correctly, i have done the following: from equalities $P(min(X_1, ..., X_n) \leq x) = 1-P(min(X_1, ..., X_n) \geq x) = 1 - (P(X_1 \geq x)^n) =  1 - (1 - P(X_1 \leq x)^n) = 1-e^{\frac{(\beta-x)n}{\alpha}}\mathbb{I}_{x \geq \beta}$. $P(\sqrt{n}(X_{(1)} - \beta) \leq x) = 1-e^{\frac{-x\sqrt{n}}{\alpha}}\mathbb{I}_{x \geq 0}$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ the distribution goes to constant $0$. Am i right?

Comment: i mean the distribution goes to distribution of constant $0$

Comment: Yes, it converges to a distribution degenerate at $0$. The theorem regarding asymptotic normality of sample quantiles does not apply here.

Comment: Could explain why this theroem could not be applied here?

Comment: @wxist Check edit.

Comment: thank you, appreciate that