# Finding maximum likelihood estimator of two unknowns.

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation, maximum-likelihood

$$f(x \mid \theta, \sigma) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\theta)}{\sigma}},$$

where $x > \theta$, $-\infty \leq \theta \leq\infty$, $\sigma > 0$.

I took two cases, first when $\sigma$ is unknown and second when $\theta$ is unknown. I then merged these two and found that MLE of $\theta$ is $x_{1}$ that is minimum ordered statistic and MLE of $\sigma$ I found is $\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x-\theta)}{n}$ and I substituted $\theta=x_{1}$ Did i do it right? Please someone tell me.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. I'm not an expert but as far as I know you should take $log(f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n))$ derive with respect to the first unknown and set it $=0$ then derive $log(f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n))$ again but with respect to the other uknown and set $=0$. Solve this system of 2 equations in 2 unknowns.

Comment: @Maffred Yes i said exactly same. Please give a try and tell me if it matches with you. I have no solution of it with me.

Comment: There is a mistake, your density does not integrate to $1$. I think the $\sigma$ in the exponent should not be squared. And you have $n$ observations?

Comment: I think @Shashi is right about the density. If you fix it, then this is a 'shifted exponential distribution' which you can google. This is partially a duplicate; you can look [_here_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693070/shifted-exponential-distribution-and-mle) for some help.

Comment: @Shashi I am so bad at this sorry i should recheck things.

Comment: @BruceET can you give a try and see if everything matches up with my MLE?

Comment: See solution [_here_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631223/finding-max-likelihood-estimators-for-the-following-shifted-exponential-pdf/1631270) for parameter $\lambda = 1/\sigma$, so $\hat \sigma = 1/\hat \lambda.$ (Then maybe check to see if MLE is unbiased for $\sigma.$). Will look back later to see if the two links I've suggested take care of this. If not, pls say what the difficulty is. In spite of the typo, my guess you have the right answers in the orig Question.

Comment: @BruceET ok let me see.

Comment: @BruceET And one more thing, for shortcut purpose in exam i don't even look at the density function when parameter is dependent on x. For example in this case i looked at $x > \theta$ and figured out that minimum ordered statistic will be MLE. Will that cause me a problem in some tricky questions?

Comment: Normally this trick helped in many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have used is fine, and what you are essentially doing is getting MLE equations for each parameter in terms of the other one, and then solving these as simultaneous equations to get the result.  This can be framed most easily as using standard calculus optimisation, with the normal working for obtaining MLEs for IID observations.  Given $n$ observations with sample mean $\bar{x}$, the log-likelihood for your problem is:

$$\ell_\boldsymbol{x}(\theta, \sigma) = - n \ln \sigma - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i - \theta}{\sigma} = - n \ln \sigma - \frac{n}{\sigma}(\bar{x} - \theta) \quad \quad \text{for } \min x_i \geqslant \theta.$$

The corresponding score equations are:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \ell_\boldsymbol{x}}{\partial \theta}(\theta, \sigma) 
&= \frac{ n}{\sigma} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{ for } \min x_i > \theta, \\[8pt]
\frac{\partial \ell_\boldsymbol{x}}{\partial \sigma}(\theta, \sigma) 
&= \frac{ n}{\sigma^2} \Big[ (\bar{x} - \theta) -\sigma \Big] \quad \quad \text{for } \min x_i > \theta, \\[8pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

From the first equation we see that the log-likelihood is strictly increasing in $\theta$ and so $\hat{\theta} = \min x_i$.  From the second score equation we then have $\hat{\sigma} = \bar{x} - \hat{\theta} = \bar{x} - \min x_i$.