# Intuition for why $X_{(1)}$ is a minimal sufficient statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $$X_i \sim f(x;\theta) = \begin{cases}1.5e^{1.5(\theta-x)}\quad \text{if} \ x\geq 0, \\ 0\quad\quad\quad \qquad \text{else.}\end{cases}$$
be iid for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $\theta$ is an unknown parameter.

I can easily show that $X_{(1)}$ will be minimal sufficient just by using Lehmann-Scheffe's Theorem, but the question says to "justify" which I interpret that there is probably a simple/intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *shifted exponential distribution* that takes $\theta$ as its
minimum possible value; $\theta$ is also the mode. So the minimum *observed*
value $X_{(1)}$ is obviously the best clue as to the value of $\theta.$

Graph of the density function for $\theta = 2.$

[image]

Here is a histogram of a sample of size $n = 100$ from this distribution.
Tick marks show locations of individual observations.

[image]

Summary statistics for this sample are as shown below. The smallest
observation $X_{(1)} = 2.002$ comes very close to the minimum possible value $\theta = 2.$

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.002   2.179   2.398   2.648   2.759   8.818
```

For more information see [*this Q&A*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693070/shifted-exponential-distribution-and-mle?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Is it a good guess because it's closest to the $\theta$ value? (Would this be the intuition for other distributions too?)

Comment: That's one way to put it. The idea of using the minimum or the maximum works for distributions for which the smallest and/or largest possible values depend on unknown parameters. Another example of the same general idea is to use the maximum value to estimate $\theta$ based on data from the distribution $\mathsf{Unif}(0, \theta).$ [For a discrete version of that see Wikipedia on the 'German Tank Problem'.]