# Sufficient Statistics and Maximum Likelihood Estimators

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, each following a two parameter exponential distribution, i.e. a distribution from the family of distributions whose probability density functions are given by:

> $$
> f(y; \sigma, \delta) = \left\{\begin{array}
> {rcl}(1/\sigma)e^{-(y-\delta)/\sigma} & \text{if}& y \geq \delta ,\\
> 0 & & \text{otherwise}
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

> (a) Find a sufficient statistic for $\theta = (\sigma, \delta)$.

I have the formula for sufficient statistics for $f_0(y)$ but don't know how to transfer the density into this formula, as in transferring the density into the exponential.
I have likelihood function

$$L=(1/\sigma^n)\exp{-(1/\sigma) sum(y_i-\delta)}$$
How can I obtain the sufficient statistic from here? is it just sum(yi)?

> (b) Does this family of distribution belong to the ($k$ parameter) exponential family? If so, for which value of $k$? Justify your answers.

I need to know how to check for the support as the support cannot depend on $\theta$.

> (c) Find the method of moment estimators for $\sigma$ and $\delta$.

I haven't done MME's at all yet, I have no idea where to start with this one.

> (d) i. Find the maximum likelihood estimators for $\sigma$ and $\delta$.
> ii. Are the estimators that you found unbiased? If not, can you find unbiased estimators based on these maximum likelihood estimators?

I have obtained the log function -nlog$\sigma-(1/\sigma)$sum(yi-$\delta)$
Would someone please help me differentiate it?

Please help if you can my teacher has not explained it well. Sorry for my notation, I have tried to fix it but am not good at coding.

Comment: Questions posted here should not be written in language suitable for assigning homework. That is probably the reason why someone down-voted this and someone voted to close it.

Comment: An answer to part of this is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461685/calculating-maximum-likelihood-ratio-using-hypotheis-testing/461725#461725

Comment: This is not an exponential family of distributions because the support of the distribution is different for different members of the family.

Comment: How can I write it suitably for next time? I am a bit confused sorry. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Say what particular difficulties you had with each part.

Comment: You need to write down the joint density with full support to answer these questions. That alone would give you sufficient statistic from Factorization theorem and answer part (b). Maximum likelihood estimators are worked out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631223/321264) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693070/321264) for example. Maybe you should  solve the first question completely before moving on to others.